# Android - Unit Testing that an activity has been started, and work on it

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I'm testing an object that's supposed to start a new activity when the open(url) method is called on it :

```
public void open(String url) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Browser.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "open:" + url);
    i.putExtra("URL", url);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

I'd like to get the instance of the activity, and check some parameters based on the URL.

I found this snipped :

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mActivity
    .getSystemService("activity");
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
```

but it only returns the name of the class, and I'd like to assert stuff on the instance of the activity.

Has anybody an idea on how to do this?

Thanks :-)

Julien

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution : the ActivityMonitor Class :

```
private Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor mBrowserActivityMonitor;

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    mBrowserActivityMonitor = new Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor(Browser.class.getName(), null, false);
    getInstrumentation().addMonitor(mBrowserActivityMonitor);
    //...
}


public void testOpen()
{
    //...

    Activity activity = mBrowserActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(5 * 1000);
    assertNotNull("Activity was not started", activity);

    //...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the kind of test you're writing, you could try the following options:

If you're writing a functional test it's worth having a look at [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/). Robotium is "a test framework created to make it easy to write powerful and robust automatic black-box test cases for Android applications". Inside the Solo class that they provide is a getCurrentActivity() method that should return an instance of the class you're looking for (under the covers it looks like they're setting an ActivityMonitor on the Instrumentation instance provided by ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2).

If you're writing unit tests and you want to check the properties of the Intent that was passed to startActivity() then you could provide your own mock/spy context instance (possibly with the help of a library like Mockito if you're running your tests on the JVM). Alternatively you could use a framework like [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) which exposes a method called get/peekNextStartedActivity() from its ShadowApplication class. See their website for more information on how to use it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to include more hyperlinks but as a new user I'm limited to 2 (bah!)

Comment: Thanks, I've voted up, you shouldn't stay a new user for long :-) I've heard about those tools, but we're trying to stick with the provided tools, as we want to integrate the tests in our continuous build. We'll have to take a look at it though.

Comment: Ok best of luck. Actually I'm using both Robotium and Robolectric with my CI builds and they're working just fine. In fact with Robolectric things are generally better than the provided tools as the tests will execute much faster, will allow you to write more specific 'unit'-style tests (which helps with defect isolation and involves writing less setup code), and since they run just like normal JUnit tests you benefit from all the additional tool/plugins support that's available out there.

Comment: Thanks, which CI, and IDE do you use? We're using TeamCity for CI and we work with Eclipse and IntelliJ

Comment: Our set up is Eclipse, Maven with the [Android Maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) and Jenkins/Hudson with the [Android Emulator plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin). The latter is nice for functional tests as it allows you to configure build matrices to target all the different device configurations you want to support. I don't have experience with Intellij or TeamCity, but my understanding is that Maven support is good in both and I *think* the Android Maven plugin will work in Intellij.